# Pipe input to two process substitutions using tee

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, tee, process-substitution

Is it possible to pipe input to two process substitutions?
Can it be done with tee? Haven't managed to find the solution.

I have a command that i want to run using process substitutions like this:

```
cat input.txt | command arg1 arg2 <(command2 </dev/stdin) arg3 <(command3 </dev/stdin) arg4
```

I am trying to pass the input through the pipe to command2 and command3 but i found out you can't read from pipe twice.

If it's possible, what's the correct syntax to do this with tee?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have reduced your example too much, but you can just do:

```
cat input.txt | command arg1 arg2 <(command2 input.txt) arg3 <(command3 input.txt) arg4
```

Or without cat.

```
<input.txt command arg1 arg2 <(command2 input.txt) arg3 <(command3 input.txt) arg4
```

But maybe there is a very complex command before the pipe. Still, why not safe this in a file first and do the above?

Still, maybe the output is very big and you don't want to write it to the file system. Then, you can make use of named pipes, but there is a catch.

```
mkfifo input{1..3} # makes input1, input2, input3 as named pipes (!! named are still part of the file system !!)
complexcommand | tee input{1..3} & # tee will hang till it can send its output, therefor move it to the background with &
<input1 command arg1 arg2 <(command2 <input2) arg3 <(command3 <input3) arg4
rm -f input{1..3} # Since named pipes are part of the filesystem, better cleanup.
```

The catch: The above may or may not work depending on the behavior of the commands. It only works if command, command2, and command3 process the data simultaneously. So, in this case if "command" decides that it needs all data from `<(command2 <input2)` before reading any data from `<input1`, it will wait forever, because a line is only send if it is requested by command, command2, and command3.

Comment: The part "cat input.txt" is only for this example, normally i receive my input through another command.  So i have to read the input through stdin, filter it into two separate parts and pass the two parts as input to the arg2 and arg3. I do the filtering with command2 and command3 but the problem is that i cant read from pipe twice. Also (sorry for not mentioning earlier) i'm not allowed to write any files on the disk and as i understand it, mkfifo creates files right? All of this has to happen on the fly. Thanks for taking time to help by the way.

Comment: @MDK What shell and version do you use? Something like coprocesses might help, but that is shell dependent.

Comment: I use GNU bash version 4.4.19. I'll check out coprocesses in case i find a solution.

Comment: @MDK I tried to get it to work, but it appears to be quite tricky. Maybe try to talk to your sysadmin to at least allow you to have have some named pipes on the file system. (Also, or you not allowed to write data to disk? Or are you not allowed to use the file system, since a named pipe contains no data!) Or ask again with the notion you cannot use the file system. (Maybe unix stackexchange gives you more answers.) Also, it does not hurt to post your complete problem as well, since there might be a different solution that's not obvious with how you present it here.